# Unable to write to cloudwatch logs despite correct permissions

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

Despite using correct permissions,
and trying to both print, and to log
to cloudwatch, I am unable to see any output.

Here is my lambda handler:

version 1

```py
def handler(event, context):
    print('here 1')
    for request in event['Records']:
        # do something
    print('here 4')

    return "Success"
```

version 2

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def handler(event, context):
    logger.info('here 1')
    for request in event['Records']:
        # do something
    logger.info('here 4')

    return "Success"
```

My code times out, and doesn't print anything to cloudwatch logs.
What's the issue?

edit:
IAM Permission Policies

```
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
AWSLambdaFullAccess
```

AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
has full cloudwatch createLogGroup, createLogStream,
and PutLogEvents access.

Comment: Can you please share the IAM policy permissions attached to the lambda? cause it seems more likely that the problem with the logs is due to a permissions issue. The timeout maybe is because of the default 3-sec lambda timeout, try to increase it to maybe 1 minute or more, depending of the load of your function.

Comment: even if I set the timeout to 15 minutes the lambda will still timeout

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the `serverless.yml` file, here is the best answer I can provide.

A quick way to verify if your function has the required permissions to log to cloudwatch.

- Go to the AWS Lambda console
- Find your function
- Select `Monitor`

If your function doesn't have permissions to log, you'll see this message:

[image: Warning message when function can't log]

If it doesn't, it would be helpful to see the `serverless.yml` file (with secrets and sensitive information redacted), and then I can help further.

Comment: Aaron, the issue was with python 3.8 lambda environment. The function wouldn't work at all which is why no logs were printed.